# Sprite object is not iterable, Platform Game (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, sprite

I am creating a platform game. I was trying to do a platform that went constantly up and down like an elevator, when i got this error: TypeError: 'Sprite' object is not iterable.

Here's the code related to the elevator:

IN SET UP:

```
self.platform_list = arcade.SpriteList()

self.elevator = arcade.Sprite()
    for i in range(600,800,32):
        self.elevator = 
arcade.Sprite("imagenes/platformer/Ground/dirt_grass.png", SCALE_PLATFORMS)
        self.elevator.center_x = i
        self.elevator.center_y = 420
        self.elevator.change_y = 2
        self.platform_list.append(self.elevator)
```

IN UPDATE:

```
self.platform_list.update()

for plat in self.elevator :
        if plat.center_y > 680 :
            plat.change_y = - 2

        if plat.center_y < 400 :
            plat.change_y = 2
```

if i change the update by replacing plat for self.elevator, and get rid of the for, only one block of the ones that conform the platform goes up and down, the rest goes up without stoping, and gets out of the screen. I have tried also changing the for by "for self.elevator in self.platform_list" and then changing plat for self.elevator, but when i execute it, all platforms move up and down.
¿How can i fix this? Please help me.